# What version of PHP was ReflectionClass introduced in?

Tags: php, reflection, version

What version of PHP was ReflectionClass introduced in?

for example:

```
$objMetaData = new ReflectionClass('Direction');
$arrValidDirections = $objMetaData->getConstants();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According [to the changes log](http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php) for PHP5, the reflection API was introduced in the second beta of PHP 5.0.0.
i suppose that *ReflectionClass* was introduced in the same time, but I'm not sure.

Comment: According to the change log methods of ReflectionClass were bug fixed in v5.1 so the class must have been introduced in v5.0.